# render option in Layer

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

Anyone know what the use of the [render option](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/deaa0ccc2ae670516a2ef1ff52fab129fd669600/src/ol/layer/Layer.js#L150)
that can be passed to Layer constructor?

it's seem that is not effect on anything or
that the render function is missing the prefix

`if(this.render) return this.render(frameState, target)`

Comment: It for for custom layers, e.g. integrating MapboxGL 
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mapbox-layer.html 
 or SVG https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/svg-layer.html

Comment: another example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/d3.html